# Fast method to estimate distance between point and polygon at direction

Tags: qgis, python, distance, shapely

(Instead of looking for the closest point between a point and a polygon I want to specify the direction that I want to measure the distance in)
I have a working code to calculate the distance between a point and polygon in different directions but the code is rather slow and I assume that I have a lot of "overhead" with my method. I have 10_000 points and 8 directions so it might be challenging to get it super fast. But this is some part of my code (**updated with example values**):

```
import math
import numpy as np
from shapely import LineString, Polygon, Point
from shapely.ops import split

def proj_point(point:Point, distance:float, direction:float) -> Point:
    new_y = point.xy[1][0] + math.cos(math.radians(direction)) * distance
    new_x = point.xy[0][0] + math.sin(math.radians(direction)) * distance
    return Point(new_x, new_y)

max_distance = 50_000
points = []
for i in range(0, 100):
    for j in range(0, 200, 2):
        points.append(Point(i, j))
polygon = Polygon(((2500, 2000), (-2500, 2000), (-2500, 4000), (2500, 4000), (2500, 2000)))
distances = {}
for i, point in enumerate(points):
    for direction in range(0, 360, 45):
        p2 = proj_point(point, max_distance, direction)
        new_line = LineString((point, p2))
        # Improved from suggestion
        # dist = split(new_line, polygon).geoms[0]
        if new_line.intersects(polygon):
            distances[i] = {direction:new_line.intersection(polygon).length}
```

**Outdated**
I then check if `dist.length` is less than `max_distance` if so I can store the distance as `dist.length`. When I have profiled my code it is the last 3 lines that uses most time (~20%, 18%, 52% (and ~10% is used on all other stuff) of the time).
**Updated**
Now the most time is spent on `proj_point` and generating the LineString `new_line`

(**update**) I tried to rotate the LineString but I couldn't find the function but I assume that it would rotate it around its centroid? I also tried to create it once and then change the coordinates but couldn't find any way to do that either :(

I have tried to look for some prebuilt function within [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) but I haven't found any so far.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by *"the distance between a point and polygon in different directions"*? Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: Just some thoughts, should be easy to try and see if this speeds things up: create the line only once, and rotate it at each step with the native geometry.rotate. You can the intersect is with the Polygon, and ask for point.distance(intersection)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing some sample data

Comment: Regarding rotating a geometry, see [`shapely.affinity.rotate`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#:~:text=shapely.affinity.rotate,(x0%2C%20y0).). You can specify the rotation origin (pivot point).

Comment: `50_000` is not a valid number. And `i` is not defined at the last line.

Comment: sorry now updated the example

Comment: Hmm for me is 50_000 a valid number (https://peps.python.org/pep-0515/) fixed the `i`, tried to use the rotate function, only create one `LineString` per point and then rotate it but it was more "expensive" (with regards to time) than generating a new LineString per point. However, using the built in `intersects` etc. instead of the `split` function reduced the time with ~50 %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/).

The trick is to compute your max_dist points out of one single point, i.e. the origin (0,0) and then apply a translation with each point in your set of 100x100 points.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Dec 27 14:00:00 2022
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov  2 2022, 18:53:38) [GCC 11.3.0]

@author: s.k.
License: MIT
"""
from math import cos, sin, radians
import numpy as np # version '1.24.0'
from time import time
import pandas as pd # version '1.5.2'
import geopandas as gpd # version '0.12.2'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# shapely version: '1.8.5.post1'
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

def sample_circle(center=np.array([0,0]), step=45, dist=50000):
    directions = np.arange(0, 360, step)
    vectors = []
    for d in directions:
        v = np.array([
            center[1] + sin(radians(d)) * dist,
            center[0] + cos(radians(d)) * dist
        ])
        vectors.append(v)

    return np.array(vectors)

polygon = Polygon((
    (2500, 2000),
    (-2500, 2000),
    (-2500, 4000),
    (2500, 4000),
    (2500, 2000)
))

vec = sample_circle()
lv = len(vec)
X, Y = np.mgrid[0:100:1, 0:200:2]
shifts = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
ls = len(shifts)
vec = np.tile(vec, reps=(ls,1))
shifts = np.repeat(shifts, repeats=lv, axis=0)

points = shifts + vec

t0 = time()
lines = []
for i in range(lv*ls):
    lines.append(LineString( [shifts[i], points[i]] ) )

print(f"lines constructed in: {time()-t0:0.2f}s!")
t0 = time()
lines_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(lines, geometry=0)
lines_gdf.rename_geometry('geometry', inplace=True)
print(f"gdf build in: {time()-t0:0.2f}s!")
t0 = time()
# this line is currently showing a warning:
intersections_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(lines_gdf.intersection(polygon), geometry=0)
intersections_gdf.rename_geometry('geometry', inplace=True)
print(f"intersections computed in: {time()-t0:0.2f}s!")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(18, 18))
intersections_gdf[~intersections_gdf.is_empty].plot()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Which is printing:

```py
lines constructed in: 0.25s!
gdf build in: 0.87s!
intersections computed in: 0.43s!
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pygeos/set_operations.py:129: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in intersection
  return lib.intersection(a, b, **kwargs)
```

And giving the next figure, which is basically a set of `30000` lines intersecting your initial polygon:

[image]

Or, for `step=8` the set of `130000` lines intersecting your initial polygon:

[image]

But if you are only interested in the distances from your points to the polygon, you can simply do:

```py
t0 = time()
points_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(map(Point, zip(shifts[:,0], shifts[:,1])), geometry=0)
points_gdf.rename_geometry('geometry', inplace=True)
distances = pd.DataFrame(points_gdf.distance(polygon))
print(f"distances computed in: {time()-t0:0.2f}s!")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16, 4))
plt.plot(distances)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Outputs:

`distances computed in: 2.06s`

and the graph of the `80000` distances between your `80000` points-orientation sets and the polygon:

[image]

If you had only a grid of 10x10 points, it would have shown these 800 distances, with 10 peaks and 10 hollows for the lowest row of 10 points and the upper one respectively:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion and nice illustrations etc.! I tried it on my computer and went from 3.4 seconds with the Shapely implementation to 1.0 seconds with geopandas.